# Incorrect Syntax Merge Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, merge, syntax-error

Quite confused, SQL server 2012 identifies a syntax issue withing the `MERGE` subquery. However, when I run the subquery stand alone it works without any issues.

Have been staring at this for a while and need some fresh eyes.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'CM'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'CS'.

```
USE [UDARepDBArchive]

INSERT INTO ZZZ_SCD

SELECT [Id]
  ,[ZZZ]
  ,[MMMMM]
  ,[VVVVVVV]                
  ,Eff_Date
  ,End_Date = CONVERT(DATETIME2,END_DATE)
  ,Current_Flag
   FROM
       
     (MERGE ZZZ_SCD CM
                 USING (SELECT [ID] = GA.ACCOUNTID
                               ,ZZZ = CASE 
                                        WHEN isnull(g.MMMMM,'0') = '0' OR ISNULL(g.VVVVVVV,'0') = '0' 
                                        THEN '0' 
                                        ELSE g.MMMMM /g.VVVVVVV
                                      END 
                               ,MMMMM = G.MMMMM
                               ,VVVVVVV = G.VVVVVVV
                       FROM UDAReporting.rbd.STRGroup G
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN UDAReporting.rbd.STRGroupAccount GA ON GA.GROUPID = G.GROUPID
                       ) CS ON CM.ID = CS.ID
                       
                       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                              INSERT VALUES (cs.[Id]
                                            ,cs.[ZZZ]
                                            ,cs.[MMMMM]
                                            ,cs.[VVVVVVV]                
                                            ,CONVERT(DATETIME2,GETDATE())                                                
                                            ,'2199-10-01 00:00:00.000' 
                                            ,'Y' )
                       WHEN MATCHED AND CM.Current_Flag = 'Y' AND (CM.ZZZ <> CS.ZZZ ) THEN
                              UPDATE SET CM.Current_Flag = 'N', CM.End_date = CONVERT(DATETIME2,GETDATE())
                 OUTPUT $Action Action_Out, cs.[Id]
                                            ,cs.[ZZZ]
                                            ,cs.[MMMMM]
                                            ,cs.[VVVVVVV]                
                                            ,CONVERT(DATETIME2,GETDATE()) AS Eff_date                                               
                                            ,'2199-10-01 00:00:00.000' End_Date
                                            ,'Y' Current_Flag
                                       
          ) AS MERGE_OUT
   WHERE MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE'
```

Comment: You can't put `MERGE` in a subquery.  I mean, you *can*.  It will just generate an error, the same was than an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` would.

Answer (score 0):

Appears the issue was caused by "SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90" on the exsisting Databases, rather than upgrading an dealing with potential issues, I'll just be creating a new Database